# How to detect when an element has scrolled into view

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building a carousel component that contains an unknown number of elements.  I want the carousel to scroll left or right when the user clicks the respective button.  The scroll right button should disappear when there is no more content off the screen on the right hand side.

My code works fine for a user clicking the buttons. However, when a user uses the tab key my carousel automatically scrolls, but my function to measure how far the carousel slides isn't detecting this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-rubin-nkgp5x?file=/src/styles.module.scss

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let box = document.getElementById("musterOverviewDocumentChecklist");
        console.log(box.getBoundingClientRect());
        let width = box.offsetWidth;

        setCanScrollLeft(-scrollDistance <= 0);
        setCanScrollRight(
            -scrollDistance >=
                (documentCategories.documents.length + 1) * 210 - width
        );
    }, [documentCategories, scrollDistance]);
```

Comment: The [W3C's APG has a good example pattern of a carousel](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/carousel/) that you could try to emulate. It makes things [accessible](https://www.w3.org/WAI/fundamentals/accessibility-intro/) which (among other things)  ensures keyboard users have the same experience as other users.

Comment: This is good. But I don't want to autoscroll

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seems pretty straightforward here, this function should disable the 'tab' key from performing at all, if you are still wanting it for some cases then just expand the if statement and make it prevent the key if another condition is met, you can also add other keys to the 'preventKeys' set if you need to prevent others from functioning too, the function might look a bit weird, it's a neat javascript trick where the function is immediately called but also callable multiple times, it works by the function declaration returning itself at the end so when you call the 'preventKeyPress' then the 'preventKeys' is called again

```
const preventKeyPress = (function preventKeys() {
    const preventKeys = new Set(['Tab']);

    addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        if (preventKeys.has(event.key)) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    return preventKeys;
})();
```

Comment: I need to allow the user to tab over content for accessibility purposes.

Comment: Please never disable the tab key altogether on a website. That will break the website for many disabled users.

Comment: I assume both of you haven't read what I wrote about the code so I suggest you do that before writing responses I've already answered, thanks.